# Parsing multi-level nested json in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's the json I am working with,

```
{
    "location": [
        {
            "location_name": "Delhi",
            "latitude": "19.07598",
            "longitude": "72.87766",
            "location_id": 1,
            "center": [
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 1",
                    "cc_id": "1",
                    "date": "10/10/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Accounting",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "95%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Avg. Overtime%",
                                    "vital_val": "1.2"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "HR",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "97%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Total Interns",
                                    "vital_val": "25%"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 2",
                    "cc_id": "2",
                    "date": "10/10/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "IT",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "99%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Avg. Overtime",
                                    "vital_val": "1.5"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location_name": "Bangalore",
            "latitude": "12.97160",
            "longitude": "77.87766",
            "location_id": 2,
            "center": [
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 3",
                    "cc_id": "3",
                    "date": "12/12/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Customer Support",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "98%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Fresh Hires",
                                    "vital_val": "35%"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is to get all the vitals for all depts under a given location. So, in case the given location is Delhi, I need the vitals data grouped by dept. and further grouped by centre. Here's my code,

```
   for (i in obj.location) {
        var data_node = obj.location[i];
        if (data_node.location_id == locId) {
          var centers = data_node.center;
          for (c in centers){
           var cc = centers[c];
             var dept_node = cc.dept;   
             var dept = dept_node;
             for (j in dept) {
                var vit = dept[j];
                for (k in vit.vitals) {

                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

But I don't think I am on the right path as it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

What I am trying is to make a table like this from the data,
[image]

Comment: What is not working? Extracting the vitals, or grouping them by dept and then centre?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @pingul it only extracts the first center and ignores other centres in the same location.

Comment: @bipashant , Question updated.

Comment: @redGREENblue So it is a html table that is the final goal, or a json object?

Comment: @pingul ..html table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, `reduce` and `map` :

```js
var a = {
    "location": [
        {
            "location_name": "Delhi",
            "latitude": "19.07598",
            "longitude": "72.87766",
            "location_id": 1,
            "center": [
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 1",
                    "cc_id": "1",
                    "date": "10/10/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Accounting",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "95%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Avg. Overtime%",
                                    "vital_val": "1.2"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "HR",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "97%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Total Interns",
                                    "vital_val": "25%"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 2",
                    "cc_id": "2",
                    "date": "10/10/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "IT",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "99%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Avg. Overtime",
                                    "vital_val": "1.5"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location_name": "Bangalore",
            "latitude": "12.97160",
            "longitude": "77.87766",
            "location_id": 2,
            "center": [
                {
                    "center_name": "Center 3",
                    "cc_id": "3",
                    "date": "12/12/2014",
                    "dept": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Customer Support",
                            "vitals": [
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Attendance",
                                    "vital_val": "98%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "vital_name": "Fresh Hires",
                                    "vital_val": "35%"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


var result = a.location.filter(function(item) {
  return item.location_name === "Delhi";
 })
 .reduce(function(element) {
  return element;
 })
 .center.map(function(element) {
  return element.dept;
 }).reduce(function(element) {
  return element
 }).map(function(element){
      return element.vitals;
    });

console.log(result)

$("body").append(JSON.stringify(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: This gets all the vitals together, which is not exactly what I am looking for. Please see the updated question for the output I am trying to get.

Comment: Give the json object you want. I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small program that outputs the table you displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = {title : "", columns : []};

    // Create table columns
    for (i in obj.location) {
        var data_node = obj.location[i];
        if (data_node.location_id == 1) {
            var centers = data_node.center;
            table.title = data_node.location_name;
            for (c in centers){
                var new_column = [];
                var cc = centers[c];
                var dept_node = cc.dept;   
                var dept = dept_node;

                new_column.push("(center_name) " + cc.center_name);
                new_column.push("(date) " + cc.date);
                for (j in dept) {
                    new_column.push("(dept -) " + dept[j].name)
                    var vit = dept[j];
                    for (k in vit.vitals) {
                        new_column.push("(vital)" + vit.vitals[k].vital_name + "& (vital_value) " + vit.vitals[k].vital_value);
                    }
                    new_column.push("");
                }
                table.columns.push(new_column);
            }
        }
    }

    // Make sure are columns are of the same length, else rendering will not work
    var maxElements = 0;
    table.columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.length > maxElements)
            maxElements = column.length;
    });

    table.columns.forEach(function(column) {
        while (column.length < maxElements) {
            column.push("");
        }
    });


    // Render all columns
    $("table tbody").append("<tr><td colspan='100'>(location_title) " + table.title + "</td></tr>");
    for (var i = 0; i < maxElements; ++i) {
        var row_cells = [];
        table.columns.forEach(function(column) {
            row_cells.push(column[i]);
        })
        console.log("<td>" + row_cells.join("</td><td>") + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + row_cells.join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>");
    }
});
```